# XercesC setting output to UTF-8

Tags: c++, xerces-c

I'm using XercesC Lib to create a serialization of my data. How can I set it to UTF-8? It is always generated with UTF-16 and I can't find a way to change that.

```
xercesc::DOMImplementation *gRegistry = xercesc::DOMImplementationRegistry::getDOMImplementation(X("Core"));
xercesc::DOMDocument *doc = gRegistry->createDocument(
        0,                      // root element namespace URI.
        X(oDocumentName.c_str()),       // root element name
        0);                 // document type object (DTD).
doc->setXmlStandalone(true);
... prepare the document ...
serializer = ((xercesc::DOMImplementationLS *)gRegistry)->createLSSerializer();
serializer->setNewLine(xercesc::XMLString::transcode("\n"));

XMLCh *xmlresult = serializer->writeToString(doc);
char *temp = xercesc::XMLString::transcode(xmlresult);
std::string result(temp);

xercesc::XMLString::release(&temp);
xercesc::XMLString::release(&xmlresult);
doc->release();
serializer->release();
getStream() << result.c_str();
```

When I deserialize with JAXB on the Java side, I always get a `content is not allowed in prolog` and so far this is the only difference I can see in the XML. When I try to locally deserialze in JAXB it works. When I take my XercesC XML I get this error. When I try to format it in Notepad++ with the XML plugin it also says that there is an error, but doesn't tell me any details.

Comment: I'm not sure, but perhaps you should build XercesC with ICU lib. See instructions for trans-coder options here http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/build-3.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the usage of [`DOMLSOutput`](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classDOMLSOutput.html), that should give you exactly what you want. I.e. you create a `DOMLSOutput` object to which you write (instead of using `DOMLSSerializer::writeToString`).

Comment: Yes, I'm currently looking into this. According to this doc http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-serial.html, the serializer can only do UTF-16. I'm trying to implement the `MemBufFormatTarget` but I don't know how to serialize the document with that.

Comment: Pretty much you'd create a `MemBufFormatTarget` and hook it up to the `DOMLSOutput`, then after that you do `DOMLSSerializer::write` to the `DOMLSOutput` object (with DOMNode being the root element of the document). Then you call `MemBufFormatTarget::getRawBuffer` and use `TranscodeFromStr` to get your XMLCh string.

Comment: Thanks. That `TranscodeFromStr` was the missing bit. It works now. :)